# Good way to do 3D vector math in language without operator overloading

Tags: graphics, operators, 3d

I would like to make a simple web application (a static website where all computation happens on the client) that generates a mesh and displays it. I have a working prototype in Unity and now I'm wondering what a good framework / language is for the task.

The problem: I would like to use Typescript or Javascript, but neither support operator overloading.

A line like this in C#

```
a = Vector3.forward * 3 + direction * length * 0.5;
```

would look horrible without operator overloading:

```
a = Vector3.forward.times(3).add(direction.times(length * 0.5));
```

What is the most elegant solution to this?

Comment: This question is in no way special to web development, so I took the freedom to remove that distracting noise from the title and and the tags.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to rewrite your application in a different language in order to present data in a browser?

Comment: @PeterM I would like to generate and present the data inside a website, wihtout a server. I updated the question to be more specific. I know that you can transpile C# to Javascript, but that creates a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Toast I think you are missing my point.  Build the data set as a 3d model any way you like, but use something like Three.js to present a 3D model on the browser.  Thus keep the 3D calc in the "Model" layer (see what I did there!) and pass that data onto a separate presentation layer  in the browser.

Comment: @PeterM I don't understand how that solves the problem. I still need to pick a programming language for the model layer / mesh generator.

Comment: There are C# libraries for creating html. It's plausible unity has that as a feature somewhere

Comment: @Caleth Where would the C# code that creates the HTML run?

Comment: The same place where the C# that creates the meshes runs.

Comment: And that is where?

Comment: @Toast The point is that you are free to choose the language that best supports what you want to do.  A  language that better supports overloading for your 3D math to build the meshes and a different language to display the meshes in the browser.  Thus making your entire issue moot.

Comment: But I'm limited by the programming languages that a browser can run. C# is not one of them.

Comment: @Toast Or if you really want to punish you can compile your c# to webassembly

Comment: @Toast I don't think I understand what you are trying to do.  Are you saying that you have built a 3D scene in Unity and now you need to replicate that scene in a stand alone file that can be loaded by a browser?  Or do you want to cast your existing Unity program into a browser?

Comment: I want to make a website where you press a button and a 3D mesh appears. I prototyped the mesh generation part in Unity to see if the logic works. It doesn't use any Unity features beyond that. Now since it should run inside a website, I planned to reimplement it in Typescript or Javascript, together with a polished HTML user interface. I'm looking for a way around the lack of operator overloading in these langauges.

Comment: @Toast You are confusing us by saying that you want to "make a website" while at the same time saying "without a server".  Most people here would assume that a website is run from a server.

Comment: @PeterM Sorry for the confusion, I tried to clarify my question even further. I would like to make a web application where all computation happens on the client, the server only serves static files. It will be hosted on a service like github.io.

Answer (score 7):

You either pick a language that allows the syntax you want, or write it out longhand and accept that it "look[s] horrible".

For vector arithmetic, there are at least 3 different operations that are reasonably denoted by `*` (or `times` or `product`), and you'd have to have a language that takes return types into account to disambiguate all of them. It's then not such a burden to have to name `scale`, `dot product` and `cross product`.

As a note, it's likely there are existing linear algebra libraries in all the languages that you could use. Don't try to write one yourself unless you really can't find one.

Comment: Could you name an example of a language that offers operator overloading and works well on a webpage? For me it's sufficient if the `*` operator only works for scaling, not the dot product or cross product.

Comment: @Toast C# is fine for generating html.

Comment: Webbrowsers can't run C#.

Comment: Soon you'll be able to compile C# to wasm, then the browser can run that.